# using a custom :store with wrap-multipart-params in ring middle ware

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I'm trying to use a custom `:store` option for `wrap-multipart-params` and instead I'm clearly getting the default store.  My custom function isn't even being called.

```
(mp/wrap-multipart-params 
   (POST "/upload-x" request (upload/upload-file request))
   {:store upload/logging-store})
```

My logging store function looks like this (it's just a dummy for now - eventually I want to handle the stream in a custom way)  None of that IO happens.

```
(defn logging-store [{filename     :filename
                      content-type :content-type
                      stream       :stream
                      :as params}]
  (println "in logging store")
  (pprint filename)
  (pprint params)
  filename)
```

upload-file looks like this:

```
(defn upload-file [{params :params
                    session :session :as request}]
  (let [user-id (:user-id session)
        files (get params "files")]
    (pprint request)
    (pprint params)
    (response/response
     {:status    :success})))
```

The printing for the request and the params clearly show the multipart params in there and that they are being handled by the temp file store:

```
 :multipart-params
 {"files"
  {:size 1674,
   :tempfile
   #<File /var/folders/rx/9ntjyyvs35qbmcbp6rhfmj200000gn/T/ring-multipart-3853352501927893381.tmp>,
   :content-type "application/octet-stream",
   :filename "blog-test.clj"}},
```

EDIT: app definition (as requested)

```
(defroutes file-list-routes
  (GET "/simple-upload" request (upload/simple-upload-file request))
  (mp/wrap-multipart-params 
   (POST "/upload-x"        request (upload/upload-file    request))
   {:store upload/logging-store})
  )


(defroutes scratch-app
  (context "/files" request file-list-routes)
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Page not found"))

(def my-app
  (handler/site
   (ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-response
    (ring.middleware.json/wrap-json-params
     (ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace
      (ring.middleware.session/wrap-session 
       scratch-app
       {:store (ring.middleware.session.memory/memory-store all-the-sessions)
        :cookie-attrs {:max-age 3600 ;in s 3600s = 1h
                       }}))))))

(ring.util.servlet/defservice my-app)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `compojure.handler/site` function contains the `wrap-multipart-params` middleware, so you're unknowingly applying the multipart middleware twice: first with the defaults, then with your custom options. Because the multipart middleware with the default options is applied first, that take priority.

Comment: Arg, I even went looking for something like that... Didn't think to go looking into there though.  Looks like there are parameters to pass the multipart params though too (assuming they were the same for the whole site.)

Comment: Why is the default one applied first, that seems kinda inside out?